# Visual Basic .Net Programming in Application Engine

Tags: vb.net, google-app-engine

Is it possible to create web-application using VB.Net in Google Application space or at least importing an application already created by VB.Net to Google Application Engine in order to run it in our Google domain?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not - the App Engine supports Java, Python or Go.  Your easiest option for running a VB.Net app on the internet is going to be leasing your own (possibly shared) server.

Comment: actually I'd say the easiest option is using Windows Azure Web Sites - http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/features/web-sites, which like GAE is a cloud deployment option

Comment: Either way, it isn't going to be hosted by Google ;o)